# Strange order of strings from order function in R

Tags: r, locale

I get the following result from ordering a vector of strings in `R` that is very strange to me. It seems this is not the same for all people.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c('(Intercept)', 'x1', 'f3', 'i', 'j', 
                      '(', '(a)', '(A)', '(x)', '(X)'), stringsAsFactors=F)
dat[order(dat$x), ,drop=F]
#              x
# 6            (
# 7          (a)
# 8          (A)
# 3           f3
# 4            i
# 1  (Intercept)
# 5            j
# 9          (x)
# 10         (X)
# 2           x1
```

I would expect the output to be

```
#              x
# 6            (
# 7          (a)
# 8          (A)
# 1  (Intercept)
# 9          (x)
# 10         (X)
# 3           f3
# 4            i
# 5            j
# 2           x1
```

Is there any settings that control how terms are sorted or what is happening? My colleague gets the expected output running the same code.

#### Session info

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Arch Linux

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] setwidth_1.0-4 colorout_1.1-2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in R 3.3.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. What is your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I can reproduce with `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Linux Mint 18 locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8   ...  attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.3.2`. I also get `sort(c("(", "a", "b", "(a", "(b")) # [1] "("  "a"  "(a" "b"  "(b"`

Comment: From `help(order)`: Except for method "radix", the sort order for character vectors will depend on the collating sequence of the locale in use: see Comparison.

Comment: Sorting order is determined by the locale. Compares the locales used between the two different R versions.

Comment: And `help("Comparison")`: Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (...). Collation of non-letters (...) is even more problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I don't really have any strange locale though. I added my sessionInfo to the question.

Comment: I added a bit more cases in the example as well. It seems it is just ignoring the brackets. I think you're onto something though. I get the same result ordering a data.frame with `dplyr` which I would guess is not using the order function internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments this seems to be related to the `locale` used rather than `R`. I get the same problem in bash.

```
$ echo "a\n(I)\n(\nx" | sort
(
a
(I)
x
```

but if I set `LC_ALL=C` I get the expected result.

```
$ echo "a\n(I)\n(\nx" | LC_ALL=C sort
(
(I)
a
x
```

I get the expected result when starting R w `LC_ALL=C`.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c('(Intercept)', 'x1', 'f3', 'i', 'j', '(', '(a)', '(A)', '(x)', '(X)'), stringsAsFactors=F)
dat[order(dat$x), ,drop=F]
#              x
# 6            (
# 8          (A)
# 1  (Intercept)
# 10         (X)
# 7          (a)
# 9          (x)
# 3           f3
# 4            i
# 5            j
# 2           x1
```

Here is my system's locale for reference:

```
$ locale                             
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```